# How can I send the output of a long-running program to stdout in tcl without fileevent?

Tags: tcl

I need to collect the output from a long running external program in Tcl. I can't use exec, because this would block until the other program has finished. So, I think I should open a pipe:

```
set pipe [open "|long_running_program" "r"]
```

but then it is not clear to me how to send the output to stdout. I'm using pure Tcl, without the event loop, so I can't use fileevent.

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is put the pipe into non-blocking mode. Then you can use `read` to get everything currently available on the pipe, ready to transfer to stdout. However, you'll need to figure out when to look for output yourself; the `fileevent` command is Tcl's solution for that, but that requires the use of an event loop. (You could start a temporary one via `update` or `vwait`, of course; using tclsh doesn't mean no event loop, but rather just means no *default* event loop.)

```
fconfigure $pipe -blocking 0

set data [read $pipe]
if {[eof $pipe]} {
    # Other side is finished; close the pipe?
} elseif {[fblocked $pipe]} {
    # No data available right now; try later
} else {
    # Print to stdout; use the newlines already in the data
    puts -nonewline $data
}
```

You should also be aware that many programs only deliver data in bursts when they're writing to a pipe. They *change their behavior* depending on whether they're writing to a pipe or to a terminal. This can matter a lot, especially if you're doing command automation; if it does to you, your best option is the Expect extension package.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying to my question. The code doesn't work for me, but perhaps, as you say, this is the nature of the application, which I don't control. But I'm surprised that your code does not have a loop to repeatedly send the output to stdout. Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: It seems to me that the code should be corrected as follows:

set pipe [open "|qclean" "r"]
fconfigure $pipe -blocking 0
while {![eof $pipe]} {
    set data [read $pipe]
    if {[fblocked $pipe]} {
        # No data available right now; try later
    } else {
        # Print to stdout; use the newlines already in the data
        puts -nonewline $data
    }
}
close $pipe